# Why is Insertion Sort O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If I gave insertion sort a reversed sorted list of numbers this is the process I follow it doing:

```
[6,5,4,3,2,1]

[5,6,4,3,3,2] - 1 compare + 1 swap

[4,5,6,3,2,1] - 2 compares + 2 swaps

[3,4,5,6,2,1] - 3 compares + 3 swaps

[2,3,4,5,6,1] - 4 compares + 4 swaps

[1,2,3,4,5,6] - 5 compares + 5 swaps.
```

In total you are doing 15 compares and 15 swaps or 30 or both and if N is 6 how is this algorithm worst case n^2 unless I am looking at it wrong?

Comment: Big-O order of complexity is an indication of the rate of growth of the time function with respect to the input size n as n tends to infinity. Google for Big-O

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases?

Comment: Check out [this animation from the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif), it shows you that your 'swap' is actually an *O(n)* operation as you have to shift all the other variables over. You potentially need to perform the *O(n)* insert operation *n* times, hence the algorithm is *O(n^2)*. Also don't forget that this is only really for extremely large values of *n*, you don't count precisely the number of operations but rather are finding a simple upper bound. Hence we can say the *O(a*n^2 + b) = O(n^2)*. It's about how the running grows when *n* does

Comment: @Dan ok I do understand performing an O(N) operation N times is definitely O(N^2), however I don't see the swap as an O(N) operation, because its not doing something in relation to ALL n elements in the list, its only doing something to the ones behind it, however I do know that I am wrong so I am trying to fix my thinking wherever it may be wrong so I must be looking at O(N) swap wrong. Does it make sense to to say that swap is O(N) because as N grows, O(N) will scale with it having to touch everything behind the current index?

Comment: @DomFarolino Yes, remember that big-O notation is the asymptotic running time, the idea isn't to specify an exact running time in terms of *n* but rather an upper bound for the running time. Constants won't matter. So I agree that you don't perform *n* operations at every "swap" (or rather *insertion*) but only *n-k* operations where *k* will depend on how far in the list you are and is between 0 and *n*. But *O(n-k) = O(n)* because the asymptotic upper boundary of the running time is still linear in *n*.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. O(n-k) = O(n) because the operations scale linearly with N even tho they are not the same value per se. It always made sense that O(n-constant) = O(n) I guess i just didn't see the K as a constant value that would be come irrelevant. I do get it now though thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you call a swap is not actually a swap. A swap involves exchanging two elements and leaving the rest of the list intact. It can be done in `O(1)` time.

What you have is a delete followed by an insert. The complexity of this operation is `O(n)` since it moves parts of the list around. Doing `n` of these operations is `O(n^2)`.

(Your definition of comparison is also not entirely clear, but I'll leave it for now.)

Answer (score 1):

O(N<sup>2</sup>) does not mean that the result will be greater than N<sup>2</sup>, only that it is going to grow proportionally to N<sup>2</sup>.

Any constant factor is allowed here. For example, the timing may be of the form

T = c*N<sup>2</sup> + d

where c and d are constants independent of N. Constant `d` is a proxy for "setup time", while `c` is a proxy for per-item operation. Other "in between" forms are possible, too - you could have linear or any other sub-square components, as long as none of them "dominates" the N<sup>2</sup>.

The idea behind N<sup>2</sup> timing is that when you double the size of the input, the time goes up roughly four times. Larger values of `d` will obscure this effect, but the difference diminishes with the growth of N.

Comment: Right I understand the role that constants play in Big-Oh notation I just have a tough time seeing insertion sort as doing O(N) operations, N times since all the swaps besides the last one will only be doing N-(current_index) swaps

Comment: I think I understand though how it can still be O(N) ops, N times since its not an exact value but more of a intuitive estimate as to how the overall operation cost will grow with N

Answer (score 0):

the [`O(n^2)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is the complexity for your compares that doesn't means you have `(n^2)` compare its the **max degree of the complexity equation** . In the worst case you will have 1+2+...+n-1 compare that is equal `(n*(n-1))/2` so its : `1/2(n^2) - n/2`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) is just a ceiling of the maximum possible 'moves', move being a mixture of comparison and/or swap.  Like any other sort, O(n^2) is for 'plain vanilla insertion sort'.  There can be variants of insertion sort, which can make it say O(n.log n), but these are variants, not insertion sort, as we know/teach it.